# SUPEE-5994 - Failed.Admin login screen detected (APPSEC-977)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, patches, admin-panel, supee-5994

I'm running the latest version of Magento, 1.9.4.2, which includes the patch SUPEE-5994.

Even with that, I'm still getting this notice their Security Scanner:

```
SUPEE-5994 - Failed.Admin login screen detected (APPSEC-977)
```

What it means and how to fix this?

Comment: This is a known issue in magento 1.9 please see response from magento team member https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Your-site-is-compromised-with-injected-JavaScript-malware/td-p/130513

Comment: You're right. TYVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is a known issue in magneto 1.9 please see reponse from magento team member.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Your-site-is-compromised-with-injected-JavaScript-malware/td-p/130513

After further investigation i found that a number of people with this issue have manually patched there files. not recommended but the option can be found

https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-5994-without-ssh/